# Maya LT 2016 Knife tool usage

Tags: maya

I am watching basic Maya 2016 LT turtorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNugJcIfFxU where 12.30 (time) shown how to use knife tool (sculpting). But when I do the same my cursor instead of cutting just freeze at the same place so nothing happends. Please, help me to understand, what may cause the problem? All my knife settings are reset and I use Maya LT 2016 version downloaded yesterday from http://www.autodesk.com/education/free-software/maya-lt

Will be very greatfull for help!

Comment: Its not a question for stackoverflow, probably you can ask some 3d forums like cgtalk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Bogdan Explanation below...

**TLDR**: I've summarized everything explained found from [this video tutorial](https://youtu.be/5MnvFPLyIs8?t=1m56s)

If you haven't figured out how to use the knife tool in sculpting, I think it may be due to the initial brush size settings of the tool being too large, (perhaps so large it's off the visible screen). To fix this, press and hold `Ctrl+B` while also click and hold the left-mouse-button, at the same time (while pressing both Ctrl+B and LMB), slide mouse to the left and if this works, a you should see a large circle close-in on the small cursor dot. That is the brush size decreasing to an appropriate size.
You can also do this after selecting the knife tool, then on the side toolbar (the panel along the left-side of Maya) find that same knife tool and double-click on the knife-tool (last tool used), the knife tool settings can be adjusted there, decrease the Brush Size and you should be able to use the knife tool as you expect.
Again this is all explained here -> https://youtu.be/5MnvFPLyIs8?t=1m56s

Hope this helps!